# Stronger Than Iron - Riddle

Tags: riddle

Here is a riddle I made up, no one has ever solved it, but I really don't think it's that hard.

> Stronger than iron
>   Harder than rock
>   Lighter than feathers
>   It's used as a lock
>
> Fast as lightning
>   Though it takes up no space
>   Many have cracked it
>   Without striking its face

Comment: Ok, why is this being downvoted? At least have the courtesy to leave a comment

Comment: How is a password stronger than iron, harder than a rock, and fast as lightning?

Comment: Not to mention that a password *does* take up some space.

Comment: @pacoverflow it is not a password, it is a cipher. A strong cipher will take considerably longer/more resources to crack than say, a chest made of iron or rock. As for "fast as lightning" ciphers are typically executed by computers, which run on electricity, which by definition is as fast as lightning

Comment: @GoldenDragon Are you referring to the sub-atomic amount of space data occupies or the non-existent amount of space that an idea takes up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll just throw out a guess of:

> password/cypher
>  They can be hard as dirt, they secure something (lock), it doesn't really take up space, and they've been broken

Comment: That would be correct, I knew this riddle wasn't hard